# How do I access the MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(...) status codes?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

I'm getting the following error `java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA` and I'd like to know what this status is. I'm using the function `MediaMetaDataRetriever.setDataSource(String filePath)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was very well buried but I found the source. [Here is a link to the error codes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ics-mr0-release/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h)

It's a build from ICS and I'm not sure where it is in the current build.

My error was a not supported error when I used a midi file.

Source:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

#ifndef MEDIA_ERRORS_H_

#define MEDIA_ERRORS_H_

#include <utils/Errors.h>

namespace android {

enum {
    MEDIA_ERROR_BASE        = -1000,

    ERROR_ALREADY_CONNECTED = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE,
    ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED     = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 1,
    ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST      = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 2,
    ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT    = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 3,
    ERROR_IO                = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 4,
    ERROR_CONNECTION_LOST   = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 5,
    ERROR_MALFORMED         = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 7,
    ERROR_OUT_OF_RANGE      = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 8,
    ERROR_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL  = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 9,
    ERROR_UNSUPPORTED       = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 10,
    ERROR_END_OF_STREAM     = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 11,

    // Not technically an error.
    INFO_FORMAT_CHANGED    = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 12,
    INFO_DISCONTINUITY     = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 13,

    // The following constant values should be in sync with
    // drm/drm_framework_common.h
    DRM_ERROR_BASE = -2000,

    ERROR_DRM_UNKNOWN                       = DRM_ERROR_BASE,
    ERROR_DRM_NO_LICENSE                    = DRM_ERROR_BASE - 1,
    ERROR_DRM_LICENSE_EXPIRED               = DRM_ERROR_BASE - 2,
    ERROR_DRM_SESSION_NOT_OPENED            = DRM_ERROR_BASE - 3,
    ERROR_DRM_DECRYPT_UNIT_NOT_INITIALIZED  = DRM_ERROR_BASE - 4,
    ERROR_DRM_DECRYPT                       = DRM_ERROR_BASE - 5,
    ERROR_DRM_CANNOT_HANDLE                 = DRM_ERROR_BASE - 6,
    ERROR_DRM_TAMPER_DETECTED               = DRM_ERROR_BASE - 7,

    // Heartbeat Error Codes
    HEARTBEAT_ERROR_BASE = -3000,

    ERROR_HEARTBEAT_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE                  = HEARTBEAT_ERROR_BASE,
    ERROR_HEARTBEAT_NO_ACTIVE_PURCHASE_AGREEMENT            = HEARTBEAT_ERROR_BASE - 1,
    ERROR_HEARTBEAT_CONCURRENT_PLAYBACK                     = HEARTBEAT_ERROR_BASE - 2,
    ERROR_HEARTBEAT_UNUSUAL_ACTIVITY                        = HEARTBEAT_ERROR_BASE - 3,
    ERROR_HEARTBEAT_STREAMING_UNAVAILABLE                   = HEARTBEAT_ERROR_BASE - 4,
    ERROR_HEARTBEAT_CANNOT_ACTIVATE_RENTAL                  = HEARTBEAT_ERROR_BASE - 5,
    ERROR_HEARTBEAT_TERMINATE_REQUESTED                     = HEARTBEAT_ERROR_BASE - 6,
};

}  // namespace android

#endif  // MEDIA_ERRORS_H_
```

Comment: FYI, if you'd like to retrieve metadata from your midi file you can try: https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.

Comment: Sorry Andrew, I don't. FFmpeg doesn't allow writing metadata without creating a new file otherwise I would modify my library to help you out. If you are only looking to change the metadata tags for a handful of formats there are several Java libraries you can use but they lack a common interface.

Comment: @AndrewOrobator how did you map `0xFFFFFFEA = -22` to any of the above enum values?

Comment: i want to know the answer,please.

Comment: i would love to know the answer too

Comment: me too, but it seems we dont get one

Comment: It is in 2's complement.

Answer (score 13):

I got this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA`  when tried to call `void setDataSource(String path)` on an empty file. (0 bytes)

You need to be 100% sure that path for the file is not null, not empty, the file itself exists and valid.

Comment: @user25 maybe it's invalid or unrecognizable format? Could you specify which file causes such error? (type, extension, size, maybe upload it somewhere?)

Answer (score 12):

I didn't have an empty file or any other of the here mentioned bugs in my code. The files I tried to use were fine. I don't exactly know why, but it worked for me when I simply used another overload of `setDataSource`.

The ones I used that threw this exception were `MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(String)` and `MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(String, HashMap)`

The one that simply worked was `MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(Context, URI)`.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error: `setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA` because the file does not exist on my device.

Answer (score 1):

I met this question when I try to use a 0 kb mp3 file,I solved it after I deleted that file.maybe you can catch this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this link to know more about error codes: https://kdave.github.io/errno.h/

By searching for **FFEA**, it tells that **0xFFFFFFEA** is decimal value **22** as [@AndrewOrobator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21010731/235123) said, the error is **EINVAL** invalid argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'm catch this error when my audio file was brocken, it solved when I change file, you can try manually set different sources paths