# setDataSource RuntimeException 0xFFFFFFEA

Tags: android, media

```
//inputStream is a MP4 file in scard.
// new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = inputStream.getFD();// value 61
retriever.setDataSource(fileDescriptor);
```

result:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA

Comment: Please check this answers. It might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009583/how-do-i-access-the-mediametadataretriever-setdatasource-status-codes

Comment: that did not help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access the MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(...) status codes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009583/how-do-i-access-the-mediametadataretriever-setdatasource-status-codes)